# Nyssa sylvatica - Identify possible disease?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases

Region is Pacific Northwest (Portland)

We have a 12 ft tall Nyssa Sylvatica that's showing significant brown leaf spotting that is worse the higher you go.  Photos are below.

Last year, while still only about 7 ft tall, its leaves turned a brilliant red in the fall without exhibiting any spotting.

Question: Is this a disease, and if so what is it and what is needed to treat it?

### Top 1/4 of tree

[image: Top 1/4 of tree]

### Top 1/4 closer detail

[image: Top 1/4 closer detail]

### Treetop

[image: Treetop]

### Mid-level branch (less discoloration)

[image: Mid-level branch]

### Lower branch (almost no discoloration)

[image: Lower branch]